# Поиск файлов по сайту с выбором типа файла

Tags: html

Как реализовать поиск файлов на сайте с возможностью выбора типа файла(видео, музыка)? Я новичек в этом деле, поэтому будь те добры поподробней.

Comment: http://site.yandex.ru/ 
https://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: Гугл и яндекс не предлагать.

Comment: Тогда ПОКАЖИТЕ ЧТО ВЫ СДЕЛАЛИ? ЧТО НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТЬСЯ? ДЕЛАТЬ ВАМ ЗДЕСЬ ВАШЕ ЗАДАНИЕ НИКТО НЕ БУДЕТ!

Comment: А хотелось бы) Но обьясните хотя бы в кратции как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим Ваш сайт будет написан на php.

Есть два варианта:

1) Хранить в базе данных всю информацию о файлах (например сделать отдельные таблицы с музыкальными файлами, с фотографиями, с видео) и производить поиск по этой базе.

2) Искать файлы напрямую в директории, где они хранятся.
Тогда производим поиск по расширению файла (например видео ищем по *.mov,* .mp4, *.avi,* .webm).

Я так понимаю, что в программировании Вы тоже новичок, поэтому сразу скажу.
Реализовать задуманное без первичных навыков (которые можно приобрести с помощью google) вряд ли удастся. Если у вас просто есть сайт и вам просто нужно сделать поиск файлов на нем (не очень понятно каких файлов, где они хранятся, но при это обучиться программированию - не ваша цель, то лучше не браться за это)...

Comment: @Андрей Суржиков, а ведь из вопроса вовсе не следует, что ТС собирается искать на своем сайте.

Может его интересует, что там лежит на каком-нибудь www.xxx.com, который он обычно смотрит через браузер?

Comment: @avp, как говорится, какой вопрос, такой и ответ..